# Update multiple records in codeigniter using active records

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to update multiple records in codeigniter using update_batch, but it doesn't work. here's my code

```
public function update {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $id_sumber = $this->input->post('id_sumber');
    $nominal = $this->input->post('nominal');
    $jumlah = count($id);
    $data = array();

    for ($x=0; $x< $jumlah; $x++){
    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $id[$x],
        'id_sumber' => $id_sumber[$x],
        'nominal' => $nominal[$x]

    );

    }
$this->db->update_batch('road_map',$data,'id');
}
```

Comment: does there any errors ?

Comment: show us id array in your question

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
$this->db->update_batch('road_map',$data,'id');
```

Id must be array of `where` condition.

Comment: where condition should be write in a $data array